# Avoiding XAML resource key conflicts in reusable WPF controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, conflict, resourcedictionary

I'm developing a WPF control and I have no control over applications where it will be used. Some XAML resource dictionary keys are obviously unique for my control, for example, `<Style TargetType="{x:Type MyControl}">`, so there is no risk of conflicts.

However, I need to use non-unique objects like `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` too. If I add it with the `"BooleanToVisibilityConverter"` key, it is possible (and likely) that the consumer of the control who includes my resource dictionary has already defined a similar converter in their code, probably with a different behavior.

Standard controls are avoiding conflicts somehow. There is a `<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="bool2VisibilityConverter" />` in `Aero.NormalColor.xaml` which is not visible for WPF applications. However, I don't know how to achieve this.

How to avoid resource name conflicts? How to make my resource names "local" for my control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually WPF controls are designed in a way which doesn't require customer to include any resource dictionaries explicitly. Assembly with WPF controls has `ThemeInfo` attribute:

```
[assembly: ThemeInfo(
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.None,
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly
)]
```

which specifies where to look for default styles, and default styles are written to `Themes/Generic.xaml` file.

Anyway, since resource dictionary key is an `object`, you can define absolutely unique keys in some internal static class:

```
internal static class ResourceKeys
{
    public static readonly object BooleanToVisibilityConverter = new object();
}
```

And use them in XAML instead of strings:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YOUR_NAMESPACE_HERE">
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="{x:Static local:ResourceKeys.BooleanToVisibilityConverter}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 1):

one solution to avoid keys is, use the `ValueConverter`as singleton

```
public sealed class SingletonValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private static SingletonValueConverter instance;

    // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
    // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
    static SingletonValueConverter() {
    }

    private SingletonValueConverter() {
    }

    public static SingletonValueConverter Instance {
    get { return instance ?? (instance = new SingletonValueConverter()); }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        return ...
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        return ...
    }
}
```

now you can use the `ValueConverter`like this

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TestProperty, Converter={x:Static local:SingletonValueConverter.Instance}}" />
```

hope this helps